# F# discriminated union syntax clarification

Tags: syntax, f#, discriminated-union

I'm reading [Expert F# 4.0](http://www.apress.com/gp/book/9781484207413) and at some point (p.93) the following syntax is introduced for `list`:

```
type 'T list =
    | ([])
    | (::) of 'T * 'T list
```

Although I understand conceptually what's going on here, I do not understand the syntax. Apparently you can put `[]` or `::` between parentheses and they mean something special.

Other symbols aren't allowed, for example `(++)` or `(||)`. So what's going on here?

And another thing is the 'operator' nature of `(::)`. Suppose I have the following (weird) type:

```
type 'T X =
    | None
    | Some of 'T * 'T X
    | (::) of 'T * 'T X
```

Now I can say:

```
let x: X<string> = Some ("", None)
```

but these aren't allowed:

```
let x: X<string> = :: ("", None)
let x: X<string> = (::) ("", None)
```

So `(::)` is actually something completely different than `Some`, although both are cases in a discriminated union.

Comment: When you put some symbols between parentheses they may mean **operator**. `([])` and `(::)` are predefined operators in F# language meaning empty list and list constructor (composition of first element and rest of the list). More about operators: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/operator-overloading

Comment: I understand that `::` and `[]` are operators but why can you have operators in union cases?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Theoretically, [F# spec](http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.0/FSharpSpec-4.0-latest.pdf) (see section 8.5) says that union case identifiers must be alphanumeric sequences starting with an upper-case letter.

However, this way of defining list cons is an ML idiomatic thing. There would be riots in the streets if we were forced to write `Cons (x, Cons(y, Cons (z, Empty)))` instead of `x :: y :: z :: []`.

So an exception was made for just these two identifiers - `([])` and `(::)`. You can use these, but only these two. Besides these two, only capitalized alphanumeric names are allowed.

However, you can define *free-standing functions* with these funny names:

```
let (++) a b = a * b
```

These functions are usually called "*operators*" and can be called via infix notation:

```
let x = 5 ++ 6   // x = 30
```

As opposed to regular functions that only support prefix notation - i.e. `f 5 6`.

There is a separate quite intricate set of rules about which characters are allowed in operators, which can be only unary, which can be only binary, which can be both, and how they define the resulting operator precedence. See section 4.1 of the spec or [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/operator-overloading) for full reference.

Comment: Thanks, this explains a lot! Strange that this isn't in the spec. There's actually another thing I don't understand and that's the 'operator' nature of `([])` and `(::)`. If you try `(||)` for example, I get an error: _Attempted to parse this as an operator name, but failed_.

Comment: Added an additional question to the original question because I still don't understand all of it.

Comment: That's because neither `[]` nor `::` are valid operator names. There is a special exception for using them as union cases, but no such exception for using them as operators.